# cakephp insert from select behavior

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Is there a "cake" way to reproduce the mysql "insert from select" behavior? I would like to get values from one model and insert in another one, without retrieving all data to my application, because there are tables with large amount of data and it will cause memory limit error.

```
Ex: $this->model1->saveAll($this->model2->find());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve that using solely Cake syntax. The best way to do this is to use [$this->model->query()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1027/query) and write your own query inside.

Comment: I expected that answer. It would be a nice thing to implement.